# Form_for each loop - position element submit outsite the loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

This is mu form:

```
.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-sm-12
  .row.userInfo
    .col-lg-12
      %h2.block-title-2 Uw gegevens staan ​​hieronder vermeld.

    .w100.clearfix
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4
        .panel.panel-default
          .panel-heading
            %h3.panel-title
              Vul uw gegevens in:
          .panel-body
            = form_for(@lead) do |f|
              .col-xs-12.col-sm-12
                .form-group.required
                  = f.label :firstname
                  %sup *
                  = f.text_field :firstname, size: 100 , :placeholder => "Voornaam", :class => "form-control"

                  = f.submit "submit", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-small" do 
                    %i.fa.fa-arrow-circle-right




    .cartFooter.w100
        .pull-right
          %a.btn.btn-primary.btn-small{:href => "checkout-2.html"}
            Gegevens juist ?  - verzenden naar Nice2stay  
            %i.fa.fa-arrow-circle-right
```

I want to add the

```
   = f.submit
```

in the .cartFooter.w100 / pull-right element. The f.submit element belongs to the form_for eah loop.  How can i do that?

Thanks..remco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular submit button needs to be inside the form element to submit the form, but one solution is place a button (outside the form) which has some javascript that submits the form, or clicks the submit button  (the latter is better if you have any other javascript which happens on the submit button click event).

```
<!-- anywhere on the page -->
<%= button_to_function "Submit", "$('#your-form-id').submit();" %>
```

I'm assuming you use jQuery here.  You can use an equivalent bit of javascript if you're not using jQuery.